# How is the parameter passed into the constructor?

Tags: python

This code:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,6,5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

     def forward(self, x):
            x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2,2))
            x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2)
            x = x.view(-1, self.num_flat_features(x))
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
            x = self.fc3(x)

            return x

    def num_flat_features(self, x):
        size = x.size()[1:]
        num_features = 1
        for s in size:
            num_features *= s

        return num_features

net = Net()

input = torch.randn(1,1,32,32)
out = net(input)

print(out)
```

I am learning python and trying to understand how this constructor works. My questions are these 2 lines:

```
input = torch.randn(1,1,32,32)
out = net(input)
```

In the **init** initialization, I can't see how the 'input' is used for initialization.

Comment: See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.randn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
net = Net()
```

calls the `__init__` method without a argument.

```
out = net(input)
```

calls the `__call__` method with `input` as argument.
Since `Net` does not implemented this, it must be implemented in the base class `nn.Module`

[here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module) you can find the sources of `nn.Module` and there is `__call__` defined with `input` as parameter.

Comment: Where is the '__call__' method?

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module  -  search `__call__`

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing an argument to a `Class` you are passing an argument to `object`. There is difference.

Following example shows how to achieve this. You need to implement `__call__` method.

```
class CallableClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)


class Net(CallableClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        pass

net = Net()
net(100)
```